# SPA static Nuxt app can't fetch static files when deployed via shared hosting, but runs fine on local server

Tags: vue.js, deployment, request, http-status-code-404, nuxt.js

I’m trying to deploy a SPA nuxt project on a subdomain hosted on a shared hosting service (Bluehost).

I ran `nuxt build && nuxt export` as per [this post](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/) and tried serving the generated static files (`dist`) on a local server, and it works fine.

But once I tried actually deploying, the page can’t load successfully and I have multiple 404s in the Network tab of Chrome devtools, saying it cant fetch all the generated static js files found in the `_nuxt` directory:

```
runtime.c59f93b.js  
commons.app.db9bcff.js
app.fe0b14c.js
```

Anyone happen to know what's causing this? Or if anything needs to be added to `nuxt.config.js`? Tried searching the docs but to no avail. The ff is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  },
  target: 'static'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61526866/how-to-make-nuxt-generated-static-spa-files-in-dist-hosted-on-aws-s3/62043755#62043755

Comment: Tried downgrading to 2.11.0, but nothing changed. Would you happen to know why that solved the issue for aws? @Rie

Comment: Seemed to be a bug on Nuxt. Can't find the issue on github anymore but it was a lengthy one with a lot of different solutions. Is your base-path setup correctly? When it throws an error in the console does it definitely show the correct path to the missing js-files?

Comment: @Rie after reading your comment I actually noticed that GET request for the files is pointing to the wrong URL, so thank you for pointing me in that direction. I will look into this but would you happen to know how to address this in Nuxt?

Comment: I don't know where the URL points to and what your "target-dir" actually is soooo, I'd need more info :D If you have it set up in a subdirectory you need to set this property though https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380719/set-path-to-output-folder-in-nuxt

Comment: @Rie thank you so much for this, I finally got it to work after editing that property by adding the full path! Yup, the issue was that I was setting it up/deploying it in a subdirectory, not as the main site, and so the base path in which nuxt was trying to fetch the files was incorrect: it was fetching from the root directory, and not the directory in which the generated `dist` folder was.

Comment: @Rie if you post below what I wrote below as an answer Id be more than happy to accept it as correct answer so you can gain rep.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer. I don't mind the rep, glad you got it working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to deploy to a subdirectory, not the main directory of the site, and so Nuxt was trying to fetch files from the wrong directory, i.e.

`/mainsite/public/commons.app.db9bcff.js`

when it should have been

`/mainsite/subdir1/dirname/public/commons.app.db9bcff.js`

The solution was to manually configure the `router` property in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
router: {
    base: '/subdir1/dirname/'
  }
```

Thank you to user @Rie for being the one who pointed out this property which ended up being the solution.